# Why do data-sort-value return None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, wikipedia

I'm scraping Wikipedia tables and I'm trying to get the population of some French cities from this website: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_du_Pas-de-Calais

For now, I don't want to use `dataframes` and I want to select my item directly by using tags. But when I ask the program to print the values of the attribute "data-sort-value", it returns a list of None while in the HTML code of the website, the attribute is the population figure. Why?

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res=requests.get("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_communes_du_Pas-de-Calais")
soup=bs(res.text,"html.parser")
tableau=soup.find('table','wikitable')
lignes = tableau.findAll("tr")

liste=[]
for ligne in lignes:
    nombre=ligne.find("td", "data-sort-value")
    print(nombre)
    liste.append(nombre)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `nombre = ligne.find("td", "data-sort-value")`, you are looking for a tag `data-sort-value`, however it's not a tag, it's an HTML attribute. If you want to search for a `<td>` which has `data-sort-value`, you can use a CSS Selector `td[data-sort-value]`.

To use a CSS Selector use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find):

```
...
for ligne in lignes:
    nombre = ligne.select_one("td[data-sort-value]")
    if nombre:
        print(nombre.text)
        liste.append(nombre)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot once again !

I have another question : do you know the diffrence between 
`tableau=soup.find('table','wikitable')` and


`tableau=soup.find("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable"})`

Comment: @AnthonySULIO I'm not exactly sure the difference. You can find this example in the docs under [keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

Comment: Ok thank you. And do you know how to get the rough data from the attribute...its value (the number) because with your code I get the following output `<td data-sort-value="1773">1 773 <small>(2018)</small>
</td>`

Comment: @AnthonySULIO Try `.text`. `.find("...").text`

Comment: I tried but I didn't work...I think I don't know how to use the method text.

Comment: Maybe because nombre's type is bs4.element.Tag @MendelG

Comment: @AnthonySULIO It's because sometimes `nombre` is `None`. I edited the answer.